# Laravel - Can't access controller when loading template through jQuery

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to load a template through `jQuery.load()` which I'm doing like this in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/steamfriends/{q}', function($q) {
    return View::make('steamfriends_list')->with("SteamFriends", Steam::user($q)->GetFriendList());
});
```

Then with jQuery in the main template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.uiFL').load('/steamfriends/{{ $user->steamId }}', callback);

        function callback()
         {
           $(".loading").hide();
         }
      });
</script>
```

Then in the `steamfriends` template (this is all content in it):

```
@forelse($SteamFriends as $friends)
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item_start" style="width:100%">
                @if(app\Http\Controllers\MyController::MyFunction($friends->steamId)) Hello World @endif
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
@empty
<i>No data available.</i>
@endforelse
```

But the problem here is that I can't access `MyController`, it gives me an error that the class is not found. How would I, in the easiest way, access the function that `MyController` holds?

Comment: Why would you want to access a controller method from a view?

Comment: The correct namespace for controllers is `App\Http\Controllers`. Don't confuse this with the folder name (Upper case A)

Comment: what's the code in `MyController`?